# how to sort/count lines with at least N identical, insensitive adjacent chars?

Tags: sorting, search

Using any tool or program preferably python or bash,
For example, in the list:

```
abc
abcd
abcdef
abCdefg
Abcdefgh
12ab12efgh
123abc346
124abc345efgh
anything
12different
```

I want to search for lines containing 4 identical insensitive adjacent chars sequence, which would return:

```
abcd
abcdef
abCdefg
Abcdefgh
12ab12efgh
123abc346
12abc345efgh
```

And possibly count occurrences of each sequence, or grouping.

abcd => abcd,abcdef,abCdefg,Abcdefgh (4)

12ab => 12ab12efgh,12abc345efgh (2)

efgh => Abcdefgh,12ab12efgh,12abc345efgh (3)

bc34 => 12abc345efgh, 123abc346 (2)

(Doing this by hand, I'm trying not to forget an occurrence :D)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If you post the code you have so far, we can help you resolve any troubles you are encountering.

Comment: I've been trying with 'uniq' command line utility but `--check-chars` option doesn't match the need. I was in hope to find an existing utility to do that rather than programming one myself...